# Define Datawave data into database and use that defined data to transformation

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

Can You please help me to transform the data from database?
I mean the transformation is defined in Database. 
I am retrieving the transformation from Database and put it in Datawave(DW).
But it is  not working. It is showing the output as string.

Following i am retrieving from database:

`flowVars.orderJsonData map
{
    phone: flowVars.orderJsonData[0].phone
}`

I put this into  variable and put into the datawave as output 
But it is working as string only.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming flow variable dwexp has the dataweave expression, you can execute that using expression-transformer. Below is the syntax

```
 <expression-transformer expression="#[dw(flowVars.dwexp,&quot;application/json&quot;)]" doc:name="Expression"/>
```

dw() function  is in the format

```
#[dw("<Dataweave script>","Output Mime type")]
```